# Converting Python Function and For Loop into OOP Class and Methods

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, oop, fuzzywuzzy

***I have a Function and a For Loop that I am using to fuzzy match records from two Dataframe that I would like to convert to OOP. When I create the function then call the function in a for loop, I receive a Dataframe of the matched results. When I try to implement the Function and For Loop using OOP, I receive a `TypeError: fuzzy_sort_ratio() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given`. How do I receive the matched results using OOP?***

#### Here is the Function

```
def match_name(name, list_names, min_score=0):

    # -1 score incase we don't get any matches
    max_score = -1

    # Returning empty name for no match as well
    max_name = ""

    # Iterating over all names in the second list
    for name2 in list_names:

        #Finding fuzzy match score
        score = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(name, name2)

        # Checking if we are above our threshold and have a better score
        if (score > min_score) & (score > max_score):
            max_name = name2
            max_score = score

    return (max_name, max_score)
```

#### Here is the For Loop

```
# List for dicts for easy DataFrame creation

dict_list = []

# iterating over df with more strains
for name in nielParent:

    # Use our method to find best match, we can set a threshold here
    match = match_name(name, df['col_name'], 50)
    
    # New dict for storing data
    dict_ = {}
    dict_.update({"Column_Name" : name})
    dict_.update({"Generic_Company" : match[0]})
    dict_.update({"score" : match[1]})
    dict_list.append(dict_)
    
merge_table = pd.DataFrame(dict_list)
```

#### What I tried to implement using OOP

```
class FuzzyMatch: 
    def __init__(self, name, list_names, min_score):
        self.name = name 
        self.list_names = list_names
        self.min_score = min_score
        
    def fuzzy_sort_ratio(self):
        
        # -1 score incase we don't get any matches 
        max_score = -1 
        
        # Return empty name for no match
        max_name = ""
        
        # List for dicts for easy DataFrame creation
        dict_list = []
        
        # Iterating over all names in second list 
        for name2 in self.list_names: 
        
            # Finding Fuzzy match score
            score = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(self.name,  name2)
            
            
            # Checking if we are above out threshold and have a better score 
            if (score > self.min_score) & (score > max_score): 
                max_name = name2
                max_score = score 
                
        return (max_name, max_score)
    
    def filteredFuzzy(self):
        
        # List for dicts for easy DataFrame creation
        dict_list = []
    
    # iterating over df with more strains
        for var in self.name:

        # Use our method to find best match, we can set a threshold here
            match = self.fuzzy_sort_ratio(var, self.list_names, self.min_score)
    
            # New dict for storing data
            dict_ = {}
            dict_.update({"Column_Name" : var})
            dict_.update({"Generic_COMPANY" : match[0]})
            dict_.update({"MATCHING_SCORE" : match[1]})
            dict_list.append(dict_)

        filtered = pd.DataFrame(dict_list)
        return filtered.sort_values(by='MATCHING_SCORE', ascending = False)
```

#### Calling the OOP Function

```
a = FuzzyMatch(name= df['col_name'], list_names=df2['PrivateName'], min_score=50)
a.filteredFuzzy()
```

#### UPDATE

```
class FuzzyMatch: 
#     def __init__(self, name, list_names):
#         self.name = name 
#         self.list_names = list_names
#         #self.min_score = min_score
        
    def fuzzy_sort_ratio(self, name, list_names, min_score):
        
        # -1 score incase we don't get any matches 
        max_score = -1 
        
        # Return empty name for no match
        max_name = ""
        
        # List for dicts for easy DataFrame creation
        dict_list = []
        
        # Iterating over all names in second list 
        for name2 in list_names: 
        
            # Finding Fuzzy match score
            score = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(name,  name2)
            
            
            # Checking if we are above out threshold and have a better score 
            if (score > min_score) & (score > max_score): 
                max_name = name2
                max_score = score 
                
        return (max_name, max_score)
    
    def filteredFuzzy(self, name, list_names, min_score):
        
        # List for dicts for easy DataFrame creation
        dict_list = []
    
    # iterating over df with more strains
        for var in name:
        # Use our method to find best match, we can set a threshold here
            match = self.fuzzy_sort_ratio(var, list_names, min_score)
    
            # New dict for storing data
            dict_ = {}
            dict_.update({"COMPANY_NAME" : var})
            dict_.update({"GENERIC_COMPANY" : match[0]})
            dict_.update({"MATCHING_SCORE" : match[1]})
            dict_list.append(dict_)

        filtered = pd.DataFrame(dict_list)
        return filtered.sort_values(by='MATCHING_SCORE', ascending = False)
```

*I was able to get the OOP method to return the matched results by removing the __init__ method and specifying the parameters in fuzzy_sort_ratio and filteredFuzzy methods. If the inputs are the same for both functions, what am I doing wrong by using the __init__ method?*

Comment: What's not clear about the error message? `def fuzzy_sort_ratio(self):` means that this function accepts _one_ argument (the `self` that's passed implicitly). But in `filteredFuzzy` you call it like this: `self.fuzzy_sort_ratio(var, self.list_names, self.min_score)` - with 3 explicit arguments and `self` - so 4 arguments total.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. If you see the example not using OOP, (calling the function in a for loop) `match = match_name(name, df['col_name'], 50)`, I need 3 arguments to call the function. I have updated the question with the solution that I found to work but I had to remove the init method and supply the parameters to each function. If the inputs are the same for both functions, what was I doing wrong by using the init method?

Comment: It has little to do with the `__init__` method and everything to do with the number of arguments you pass to `fuzzy_sort_ratio`. You must pass exactly as many positional arguments as required: in your second example, `fuzzy_sort_ratio` requires 4 arguments, and you correctly pass 4 arguments by calling it like `self.fuzzy_sort_ratio(var, list_names, min_score)` (as always, `self` is passed automatically). You can uncomment the `__init__` method in the second code, and it'll work just as well as the current version.